Custom newline chracter in python socketserver.StreamRequestHandler
I'm implementing a socket server for python. Ideally I would use a socketserver.TCPServer in combination with thereadline-functionality of socketserver.StreamRequestHandler, see for instance the example in the documentation. Unfortunaltely I have to use a custom newline character other than \n.
Is there a way to change this newline character in this context? Accoding to my debugger the rfile-attribute of socketserver.StreamRequestHandler, is a  _io.BufferedReader-object but I couldn't find any documentation about that.

What is your custom newline character(s)?

No, there is not a way to change the newline character.  rfile is an io.BufferedReader which is a buffered binary stream which inherits the readline() method from io.IOBase (emphasis mine)

readline(size=-1, /)
Read and return one line from the stream. If size
is specified, at most size bytes will be read.
The line terminator is always b'\n' for binary files; for text files,
the newline argument to open() can be used to select the line
terminator(s) recognized.

You can buffer your own fixed reads and extract messages using your own newline character(s) with code like the following:
import socketserver as ss
import threading
import socket

class MyTCPHandler(ss.StreamRequestHandler):

    _buffer = b''
    LINEEND = b'xy'

    def handle(self):
        while True:
            line = self.read_until(self.LINEEND)
            if not line: break
            print(line)

    def read_until(self, terminator):
        while terminator not in self._buffer:
            chunk = self.request.recv(1024)
            if not chunk: break
            self._buffer += chunk
        msg, _, self._buffer = self._buffer.partition(terminator)
        return msg

def server():
    with ss.ThreadingTCPServer(('', 5000), MyTCPHandler) as server:
        server.serve_forever()

threading.Thread(target=server, daemon=True).start()

# client 1
with socket.socket() as client1, socket.socket() as client2:
    client1.connect(('localhost', 5000))
    client2.connect(('localhost', 5000))

    client1.sendall(b'client 1 message 1xyclient 1')
    client2.sendall(b'client 2 message 1xyclient 2')
    client1.sendall(b' message 2xyclient 1 message 3xy')
    client2.sendall(b' message 2xyclient 2 message 3xy')

Output:
b'client 1 message 1'
b'client 2 message 1'
b'client 1 message 2'
b'client 2 message 2'
b'client 1 message 3'
b'client 2 message 3'


Yeah, I already figured that something like this would have to be plan B. Thanks for the effort!
